# ! I can't find file `ydocstrip.tex

Tags: installing

I recently had to download the package adjustbox from CTAN and when I ran the .tex file, I had this error above . The ydocstrip is the first line of the .tex file in the adjustbox backage.
Does anyone have a clue how to fix this?

Comment: What TeX distribution do you run? In general it's discouraged to download from CTAN, because it's better to use the method provided by the distribution. Is it MiKTeX or TeX Live? On what operating system?

Comment: in general (as @egreg says) it’s best to use your distribution’s copies of these things.  the `ydoc` package _is_ available on ctan, but installing package straight from the archive isn’t everyone's idea of fun ... and `ydoc` is available in the major distributions.

Comment: (and in any case, what do you have that needs ydoc?  it’s a pretty unlikely thing for any run of the mill package to ask for.)

Comment: Hi :I needed to use "adjustbox" but it did not run because I do not have the package. When I got the package from CTAN, I saved the .dtx files and the .tex file, then I ran the .tex in Latex; I use texmaker and miktex2.9. My computer is 64 bit but the texmaker and miktex I downloaded was the same for 32 and 64 bit.

Comment: It looks like the ydoc is written in the first line of the .tex adjustbox file. My question now is, if I get a new installation for Miktex, will that affect my thesis files?, in the past months I downloaded several packages from CTAN. So, will doing a new installation affect my previous chapters?. And, if it does not , can you give me the right link to download miktex from?.

Comment: @Naema: Don't worry about your thesis. The `adjustbox.ins` (there is no `adjustbox.tex`) is just for unpacking the `.sty` files from the `.dtx` file. This is the old, manual way to unpack and install files. This needs the `ydoc` file installed first, which is also on CTAN. However, you don't need this for modern LaTeX distributions which provide binary packages. See also my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To install adjustbox package:

- run `Start\MikTeX 2.9\Maintenance (Admin)\Package manager (Admin)`
- write `adjustbox` into the "Name" field and press `Enter`
- click on `+` symbol and confirm installation

and you're ready to use it!

If this doesn't work you should install `adjustbox` manually.

- You can find `adjustbox.sty` here: [adjustbox.tds.zip](http://mirrors.ctan.org/install/macros/latex/contrib/adjustbox.tds.zip)
- unpack the whole content directly into `MikTeX 2.9` folder
- run `Start\MikTeX 2.9\Maintenance (Admin)\Settings (Admin)`
- execute `Refresh FNDB` and `Update Formats`

and you're ready to use it!

Comment: @Naema did you try this?

Comment: Is this the procedure on Windows-MikTeX? Please add this piece of info to your answer! (OS was not specified in the question...)

Comment: RicoRally, I tried the first solution and after I pressed (+) to update the installation, another window appeared asking me for name and password (proxy authentication required)! what are those name and password?

Comment: @Naema I think this is something related to your computer, not LaTeX. Is it a `MAC OSX`? Maybe it is your name and password.

Comment: thanks a lot RicoRally, I tried the second method (manually) and it worked!. My computer is running windows 7 , 64 bit.

Comment: Glad to help. I hope you'll find those name and password for further installations on your OS. @MattAllegro MikTeX is specifically built to be used in MS Windows. In this case the OS was somewhat implied.

Comment: @RicoRally True, great! I felt like some context was missing but the 1st comment by egreg to the question was pointing it out already

Answer (score 3):

`ydocstrip` is only required if you want to unpack the `.sty` file from the `.dtx` file yourself. 
If you really want to do this you need to install the [`ydoc`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/ydoc/ydoc.dtx) package first. However, both MikTeX and TeX Live provide all my packages (I'm the author of `adjustbox` and `ydoc`) as installable packages, so there should be no need for this.

Also I provide a [TDS Zip file](http://mirrors.ctan.org/install/macros/latex/contrib/adjustbox.tds.zip) with the final `.sty` on CTAN which can be used for manual installs like mentioned in RicoRally's answer. Simply unpack it over your TEXMF directory (under Linux usually `~/texmf`).

---

Linux users might want to consider installing TeX Live directly (
[How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu)) and simply use `tlmgr install adjustbox`.

Comment: Unfortunately the TeX Live version of some older but still used OS (like Ubuntu 12.04) do not contain adjustbox, so there might be situations where manual installation is the only reasonable choice. If someone is not familiar with TDS archives the second solution in RicoRally's answer might mistakenly interpreted as MikTex (i.e. Windows) specific (it happened to me). @Martin_Scharrer: Thanks for making that point more clear. Anyway, IMHO it would be useful to mention the ydoc dependency somewhere. And of course: Thanks for the devolpment work!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem (`I can't find file 'ydocstrip.tex'` when running `latex adjustbox.ins`).
However, RicoRally's solution did not apply as I am using Kubuntu (12.04 LTS).

My solution (or workarround): downloading the package [`ydoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ydoc): by [Martin Scharrer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2975/martin-scharrer) (the author of [adjustbox](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox)), and copy the file to the adjustbox directory. Then `latex adjustbox.ins` run without problems. Next step: copy all the `.sty`-files and tc-pgf.def to `~/texmf/tex/latex/adjustbox/`

To use the adjustbox package, I had also apply that same procedure to the package [`collectbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/collectbox), which is a dependency of adjustbox.

Background (for search engines): This was necessary to compile the latex output from nbconvert (IPython notebook).

Comment: @Martin_Scharrer: Is this behavior a problem with my configuration or is the file ydocstrip.tex indeed missing from the adjustbox package.

Comment: This is not an answer, you should probably ask a new question instead

Comment: In my opinion this is a solution to the problem or, in other words, an answer to the original question 'Does anyone have a clue how to fix this?'. It shows a possibility how to install the adjustbox package.